# Token Expired - JSON REST API - Error Code

Tags: web-services, rest, api-design

I've got a JSON REST API. There is a handshake that will give you a token that is valid for 15 minutes. All calls you do within those 15 minutes should work ok. After the 15 minutes I am returning an error object (includes code, message, success = false) but I was also wondering what HTTP Error Code I should return? And will using a HTTP error code mess up certain clients? (HTML5, iPhone, Android). What is considered best practice in this scenario?

Comment: +1, great question. Did you ever find a good solution to this? (btw - both [netflix](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/read/HTTP_Status_Codes) and [linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens) returns a 401).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What status code should I use when session token is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613088/what-status-code-should-i-use-when-session-token-is-invalid)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim This question is already older

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Answer (score 119):

You should return a `401 Unauthorized` Status Code. You might additionally provide hypermedia to establish the token again

Think about what happens in a web app. You go to say a banking site. If not auth'd it will send you to the log in page. Then you log in and you are good to go for a time. Then it expires and the cycle repeats.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 55):

according to the spec rfc6750 - "The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage", https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750, p.8, section 3.1, resource server should return 401:

> invalid_token
> The access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed, or
> invalid for other reasons.  The resource SHOULD respond with
> the HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code.  The client MAY
> request a new access token and retry the protected resource
> request.

Comment: Note _SHOULD_ vs. _MUST_. As a caller, would be nice to be able to rely on 401. Oh well.

Answer (score 16):

FWIW Facebook uses 400 with a custom JSON response.  I personally would prefer 401 with custom JSON response.

Here is FB's response body:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Jul 17, 2014 9:00am. The current time is Jul 17, 2014 9:07am.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "error_subcode": 463
  }
}
```

Comment: Something tells me Facebook should be treated as exception, not guideline for development. Just saying.

Comment: Is it a call to Facebook as to an authorization server, or to a resource provider? The  authorization server should return 400 : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2 , but the resource provider should return 401